# Add an extra "number place" in my countdown with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this time to countdown and i've got that working. But when it goes below 10 seconds I want it to display 00:09 instead of 00:9.

How can I achieve this?

```
var timerbtn = document.getElementById("timer");
var counter = 20;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "00:20";
var id;
timerbtn.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, timerbtn);

    function startTimer() {
this.style.display = 'none';
id = setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0) {
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(timerbtn, newElement);
        clearInterval(id);
     } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = "00:" +counter.toString() + "";
    }
     }, 1000);
    };

 var clickbtn = document.getElementById("btn");
 clickbtn.onclick = startTimer;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5cfjvhf/)

Comment: You can replace `counter.toString()` by  `('0'+counter).slice(-2)`. Maybe a better way, but work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here man: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/q5cfjvhf/2/

You just need to add a condition to append the zero:

```
var timerbtn = document.getElementById("timer");
var counter = 20;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "00:20";
var id;

timerbtn.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, timerbtn);

function startTimer() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    id = setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        if (counter < 0) {
            newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(timerbtn, newElement);
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            if(counter < 10) {
            newElement.innerHTML = "00:0" +counter+ "";
            }else{
                newElement.innerHTML = "00:" +counter + "";
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
};

var clickbtn = document.getElementById("btn");
clickbtn.onclick = startTimer;
```

Comment: ... and there's really no need at all for the `.toString()` call

Comment: yup, Pointy is right, since you are trying to concatenate a string with a number, javascript will treate both values as a string. Thanks Pointy

Comment: oh cool thanks, i can accept it as an answer in 5 more minutes. Also if i remove the .toString() do i just leave the +counter then?   and...would it be easy to add a action after the clock reaches 0?

Answer (score 0):

Add string "0" before showing at out put .. like ( "0"+9) will give 09..

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `counter.toString()` by `('0'+counter).slice(-2)`.

If you go to more complex display try using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it's pretty great for time formating.

Comment: Thanks, I have not come across this. I will look into it. Would it be easy to add a action after the clock reaches 0?

Comment: Not especially easier than current method.